# How to translate a basic javascript variable in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

How can I translate this :

```
var start = Date.now();
var end = Date.now() + 604800000;
```

to `vue.js`? Is it in `methods`? `actions`?

Is something like this correct?

```
actions: {
    start ({commit, getters}, payload) {
        var start = Date.now()
    },
```

Comment: vue.js is javascript.  Technically no 'translation' required.  It really depends on what you're trying to accomplish.  Maybe tell us more about your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to use vuejs or Vuex? `actions` is a reserved to register actions on a Vuex store. You can find below how to translate your code in a simple Vue instance.

**index.html**

```
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>
```

**main.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  template: "<p> {{ end }}</p>",
  data: {
    start: null
  },
  mounted() {
    this.start = Date.now();
  },
  computed: {
    end() {
      return this.start + 604800000;
    }
  }
});
```

For this example, `start` is calculated when the vue instance is `mounted` on the `<div id="app"></div>` block. `end` is a computed property that will be calculated as soon as the `start` property value has changed.

Have a look at [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html), they describe a similar example.